# How to make concrete implementation more generic

Tags: c#, .net

I have this interface

```
 public interface IMapper
{
    bool CanMap(List<Field> fields);
    AccountHolder Map(List<Field> fields);
}
```

I have multiple classes that implements this interface. Given below is an example of this implementation.

```
public class DepositorMapper : IMapper
{
    private readonly IFormUIElementHelper _formHelper;

    public DepositorMapper(IFormUIElementHelper formHelper)
    {
        _formHelper = formHelper;          
    }

    public bool CanMap(List<Fields> fields)
    {
        var taxId = _formHelper.GetFieldValue<string>(fields, FormsAttributes.DepositorTaxId);

        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DepositorTaxId);
    }
}
```

The only difference in each concrete implementation is the  'FormsAttributes.DepositorTaxId'. How can i make this more generic?

Comment: could you elaborate upon what you mean by 'more generic'?

Comment: Should we move this into [SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an abstract class like that:

```
public abstract class BaseDepositorMapper : IMapper
{
    private readonly IFormUIElementHelper _formHelper;

    public BaseDepositorMapper (IFormUIElementHelper formHelper)
    {
        _formHelper = formHelper;          
    }

    public bool CanMap(List<Fields> fields)
    {
        var taxId = _formHelper.GetFieldValue<string>(fields, GetDepositorTaxId());

        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(taxId);
    }

    public abstract DepositorTaxIdType GetDepositorTaxId();
}
```

Comment: `GetDepositorTaxId` should probably be `protected` in this design, not public.  It may also be better as a property, although that could depend on the specifics.

Comment: Thanks! Rom Eh and Servy. We did it with a property.